# Minimizing IOPS with Fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I have a Fortran program that writes out a large amount of ASCII data, one line at-a-time, and there is some concern from system admins (and evidence from my runs) that this is adversely affecting system performance.  I/O generally works better for fewer big writes than many small writes.  So, I'd like to get the program to minimize the number of IOPS by writing out bigger chunks of data without changing the format of the output file (this is a large set of software with lots of related software depending on assumed file formats).  I had thought turning a loop like this:

```
  nwrite=100000000       !total number of lines to write
  do cnt=1,nwrite
     write(11,'(i22,3x,f16.14)')cnt,numar(cnt)
  enddo
```

into a loop like this:

```
  nwrite=100000000
  nblock=10000         !number of lines to write in each block
  do cnt=1,nwrite/nblock
     write(11,'(i22,3x,f16.14)')(nblock*(cnt-1)+j,numar(nblock*(cnt-1)+j),j=1,nblock)
  enddo
```

would do the trick.  But I made two small scripts doing the above and they didn't show any real difference in run time.  It's a fairly major time commitment to make the change in the actual code, so I'd like to be fairly sure before committing to an approach.  I haven't completely unrolled the loop into a single write command because that might not work well for my current problem, though approaches that do this are also welcome.

Can anyone confirm whether the above code would reduce the actual number of write commands or what else might achieve what I'm looking for?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using ifort you might try the option `-assume buffered_io` to buffer the output.

Comment: The software is used across a number of different systems with different compilers, so I'd prefer an option that isn't dependent upon compile-time options.

Comment: For really large amounts of data you might look into specialized (and portable) libraries like [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) or [netCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/). While writing ASCII is pretty simple, it usually is unfeasible as soon as a lot of IO is required.

Comment: Are you opposed to binary output or using a library like HDF5 or netCDF?

Comment: There's a very large amount of code written by various parties that depends on the file formats in place, which is why I haven't switched to a tighter format like netCDF.

Comment: @casey does your comment about buffered io mean that how I/O is done is handled by the compiler and not directly controllable by the code?

Comment: Yes, it is done by the run-time library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on input from other users and reading more, Fortran leaves control over this to the compiler, therefore it is compiler-dependent.  Buffered writes are the default behavior for the Portland Group Fortran compiler, and it looks to be the same for GFortran.  Intel does not buffer files by default.  For the Intel compiler, adding the option `-assume buffered_io` will make file I/O buffered by default.